# Laravel : How to convert time to number of minutes?

Tags: php, string, laravel, split

In laravel suppose i have input like this '10:30:00' an i want to split them by ":" and covert them into integers and add them like here it will be 10+30=40 will be the output. i used 'explode' to split but i don't know how to add the values.if anyone can help please...thanks.here is my sample code where i am taking time as string.this is not duplicate question as i want to use the exploid function to be used and taking input from user as string. not as time. the question is showing as duplicate of my question is about time only. :)

```
$startTime= $request->input('starttime');
$finishTime=$request->input('endtime');
$stime = explode(':',$startTime);
$estime = explode(':',$finishTime);
```

Comment: Why you want to add minutes and hours ?

Comment: i want to know the way to add them..i will multiply the hour by 60 and add with minutes. i want the output in minutes.

Comment: For laravel I prefer to use Carbon as @kapil.dev answer you. It is not good practice to explode the time and add minutes and hours only. Secounds are also useful in some cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `array_sum($array_name);`

**Before Performing array_sum You will have to do $stime[0]*60 and $etime[0]*60 so as to convert them into minutes**

for `$stime` do `$startsum = array_sum($stime);`

and for `$etime` do `$endsum =array_sum($etime);`

Hope this Helps You.

Comment: if i do this  $stime[0]*60 and $etime[0]*60 then how will i pass the value into array_sum()?

Comment: you will have to store back into $stime[0] = $stime[0]*60 and similarly for $etime[0] = $etime[0]*60

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Carbon` to extract Hour and Minute

```
$startTime= \Carbon::parse($request->input('starttime'));
$stime = ($startTime->hour * 60) + $startTime->minute;
$finishTime=\Carbon::parse($request->input('endtime'));
$estime = ($finishTime->hour * 60) + $finishTime->minute;
```

To know more about Carbon refer : http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-interval

Answer (score 1):

Did you try like this....

```
<?php
$time='10:30:00';
$stime = explode(':',$time);


$sum=0;
foreach ($stime as $s)
{
    $sum=$sum+$s;
}
echo $sum;

?>
```

And if you to use `array_sum()`..try like this...

```
$sum=array_sum($stime);
echo $sum;
```

Comment: yeah by using array_sum() i got the desired output

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [date_parse](http://php.net/date-parse) method for php.

```
<?php 
$startTime= '10:30:02';
$finishTime= '12:30:20';

$parsed = date_parse($startTime);
$startTimeSeconds = $parsed['hour'] * 3600 + $parsed['minute'] * 60 + $parsed['second'];

$parsed = date_parse($finishTime);
$finishTimeSeconds = $parsed['hour'] * 3600 + $parsed['minute'] * 60 + $parsed['second'];

?>
```